# C++20 standard library compile error for module on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, std, c++20, clang++

Here are my test code and build scripts.

testmodule.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
export module testmodule;
export int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

import testmodule;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Test Modules" << endl;
    cout << "add 1 and 2 is " << add(1,2) << endl;
}
```

build.sh

```
rm *.o
rm *.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts -Wall -v -c -ferror-limit=1 -Xclang -emit-module-interface testmodule.cpp -o testmodule.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts -Wall -v -c -ferror-limit=1 -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cpp -o main.o
clang++ -fmodules-ts -o main main.o *.pcm
```

When I run the `build.sh`, I got the following compile errors:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=12.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 819.6 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wall -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/bf/Workspaces/C-plus-plus-Playground/validateC++20 -ferror-limit 1 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fmodules-ts -fno-implicit-modules -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o main.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
In module 'testmodule' imported from main.cpp:3:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:216:20: error: 'std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<<' from module 'testmodule.<global>' is not present in definition of 'std::ostream' provided earlier
    basic_ostream& operator<<(nullptr_t)
                   ^
```

If I comment out the line #1 in `testmodule.cpp` and run `build.sh`, I'll get a `main` binary as expected.

```
% ./main 
Test Modules
add 1 and 2 is 3
```

It seems that I cannot include std libraries in both `main.cpp` and `testmodule.cpp`.

Any idea where I can start to look into this?

[Update 2022-10-18]
With Remy's suggestion, I tried `import <iostream>;` in testmodule.cpp, and got the following errors,

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name testmodule.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=12.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 819.6 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wall -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/bf/Workspaces/C-plus-plus-Playground/validateC++20 -ferror-limit 1 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fmodules-ts -fno-implicit-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -emit-module-interface -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o testmodule.pcm -x c++ testmodule.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
testmodule.cpp:2:8: error: expected a module name after 'import'
import <iostream>;
       ^
```

[update Tue Oct 18 2:38PM]
Thanks for sigma's comments. I moved [export] section to the beginning of the code. I added `cout` statement in `testmodule.cpp` to make iostream required in testmodule.cpp. After the modification I still see compile errors when compile main.cpp

```
  1 // testmodule.cpp
  2 export module testmodule;
  3 #include <iostream>
  4 export int add(int a, int b)
  5 {
  6     std::cout << "in add()\n";
  7     return a + b;
  8 }

  1 // main.cpp
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 
  4 import testmodule;
  5 
  6 using namespace std;
  7 
  8 int main() {
  9     cout << "Test Modules" << endl;
 10     cout << "add 1 and 2 is " << add(1,2) << endl;
 11 }
```

```
% clang++ -fmodules-ts -Wall -c -ferror-limit=1 -Xclang -emit-module-interface testmodule.cpp -o testmodule.pcm
% clang++ -fmodules-ts -Wall -v -c -ferror-limit=1 -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cpp -o main.o
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx12.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=12.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 819.6 -v -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wall -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-bitwise-instead-of-logical -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/bf/Workspaces/C-plus-plus-Playground/validateC++20/try001 -ferror-limit 1 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fmodules-ts -fno-implicit-modules -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o main.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
In module 'testmodule' imported from main.cpp:3:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:436:43: error: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' from module 'testmodule' is not present in definition of 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>' provided earlier
  static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp      value = __v;
                                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:436:43: note: declaration of 'value' does not match
  static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp      value = __v;
                                          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
```

[update 2022-10-19]
Thanks sigma. I did some further tests on module fragment test. It seems the clang++ on macOS does not fully support c++ module.
Code,

```
// interface_part.cppm
export module M:interface_part;
export void World();
```

Compile command and output,

```
% clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts interface_part.cppm --precompile -o M-interface_part.pcm
interface_part.cppm:2:16: error: sorry, module partitions are not yet supported
export module M:interface_part;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: In this example, there is no reason for `testmodule.cpp` to use `#include <iostream>` at all. But, if you just, then try `import <iostream>;` instead.

Comment: use import <iostream>; I got the following,

testmodule.cpp:1:8: error: expected a module name after 'import'
import <iostream>;
       ^

Comment: The `[export] module ...;` has to come before the include macro. This is the statement that defines the name of your module, it may only be preceded by a `module;` global module fragment. Since you still don't need iostream in the module, just delete it ;)

Comment: see my recent update. still errors when compile ```main.cpp```

Comment: Hmm... Since I have no experience with modules so far, I can only provide guesswork for now. My strong suspicion is that the double inclusion of iostream is problematic here, because one is inside the module and the other is not. It could be that your code is invalid, or the compiler is rejecting valid code, I'm not sure how this situation should be handled. You might have to put the module's `#include` in a global module fragment or be forced to use only import statements, depending on Apple clang's implementation.